# Help with a proof using the Schröder-Bernstein theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

#### Suppose that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets with $|A|=|B|$.  Show that $f$ is one-to-one if and only if it is onto.

My prof. wants us to use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem to prove this. I am not really sure how to go about solving this at all any

Comment: Do you mean $|A| = |B|$?

Comment: Yah its $|A| = |B|$. It looks like our professor copied it wrong from the book to our handout. I think that makes more sense now.

Comment: Ok, so based on that I can prove that f is one-to-one based on the theorem, but I am not sure how to show that it is only one-to-one if it is onto.

Comment: it seems highly unlikely to use CSB here. Prove by induction makes much more sense. I really don't see what the instructor intended with this question. I'm curious...

Answer (score 0):

Draw some diagrams. Draw a vertical line of say, 5 dots, and then another one about 10cm away. Call them $A$ and $B$. Draw lines from the dots in $A$ to the dots in $B$ (i.e., represent some function) and get a feel for why injectivity and surjectivity are equivalent for finite sets of the same size (and so further, understand why one need only check for either injectivity or surjectivity to be sure of bijectivity). I would imagine from this it will begin to become transparent, and a proof should come to mind.

Comment: this does not quite answer the question. The question was how to use CSB in order to prove this result. Personally though, I don't quite understand what the instructor had in mind.

Comment: To me, CSB says if $f:A\mapsto B$ and $g:B\mapsto A$ are both injective then a bijection $h$ exists. I don't really see why you'd want to use that at all! I thought some advice leading to a proof would be better than nothing..